# Java: Runnable vs Callable - When to use

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The difference between the Runnable and Callable interfaces in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141284/the-difference-between-the-runnable-and-callable-interfaces-in-java)

What are the differences in the applications of Runnable and Callable. Is the difference only with the return parameter present in callable. Can you please provide a simple example which demonstrates the typical use of both.

What is the need of having both if Callable can do all that Runnable does.