# How to use ExecutorService to handle an aborted Runnable?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I have a `Worker` class that `implements Runnable` and has a `run()` method which may raise exceptions in the event of a conflict, and return early. When it does, that thread needs to be put back into the queue to be run again.

From looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141284/the-difference-between-the-runnable-and-callable-interfaces-in-java) question, it seems I need to rewrite with `Callable`. Is that correct? There's no way to do this with `Runnable`?

Comment: Just use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29

Comment: I've already read that. It lists methods and types and all but doesn't give any examples or say anything about exception handling with Runnables. I edited the question to be clearer.

Comment: You could also have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html)

Comment: Are you concerned that a `Runnable` which throws an uncaught runtime exception won't be returned to the pool?

Comment: Part of my `run()` method involves this: `try{//thingThatThrowsException}catch (TransactionAbortException e){return;}` I'm afraid that yes, if it returns here, the Runnable will not do its job.

Comment: If you're handling the exception in the `Runnable`, why not return it to the pool there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can have the worker thread do it itself.  If you have control of the executor.

```
class RequeableWorker implement Runnable{
  private final ExecutorService e;
  public RequeableWorker(ExecutorService e){this.e =e;}

  public void run(){
     try{
        //do work
     }catch(RuntimeException ex){
        e.submit(this);
        throw ex;
     }
  }
}
```

Or as your answer suggests having the waiting thread of a Future re-queue.

```
public void workOrRequeue(){
    for(;;){
       Future<?> future = e.submit(someCallable());
       try{
          future.get();
          return;
       }catch(ExecutionException ex){
          //maybe log, ex.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...You can do that? that will work? If I declare an ExecutorService in the main thread, I can pass it in as an argument to the worker, and have the worker resubmit itself to the queue?

Comment: What if the worker takes other arguments? When it resubmits itself to the queue, will they be included in the new submission as well?

Comment: @Aerovistae Generally speaking, the ExecutorService is composed of a work queue and threads.  If you pass the ExecutorService and submit to it you are simply placing the runnable on the ES work queue.  It is simply delegating, you can see it is done here too http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html

Comment: That poses a different sort of problem.  If the worker needs to be re defined you are posed with the concern of having the ES do too much work retrieving the new data.  If the ES cannot actually get this new data you need to use the second example I listed.  Lastly, if the RequeableWorker can in fact attain the new parameters then you can just get them before `submit`ing

Answer (score 2):

As say the docs for [`Future.get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29):

> #### Throws:
>
> [...]
>
> `ExecutionException` - if the computation threw an exception