# Shall Callable be preferred over Runnable?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have understood the difference between `Runnable` and `Callable` interface in Java. From Java 1.5 additional features has been added to `Runnable` interface and has been called `Callable` in order to maintain backward compatibility.

My questions is now that we have `Callable` interface, shall we always use that? What are the use cases of not using `Callable` and using `Runnable`?

([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141284/the-difference-between-the-runnable-and-callable-interfaces-in-java) is a good article on what are the differences between them)

Comment: After reading the answers in the linked question, what *practical* problem/question remains? Either the benefits of Callable are needed .. or they are not.

Comment: @user2246674 The benefits of Callable are vivid. I don't see any point in using Runnable any more after having Callable in hand. Do you?

Comment: I do. There is likely code that requires a Runnable, in which case a Callable is not adequate. Neither Callable nor Runnable unify below Object. Also, why use a Callable is not needing the features of Callable? What if there is *no* return value - return `null` typed as an Object?

Comment: @user2246674 sure when you are forced to use Runnable then you have to. But when you are free to chose between Runnable and Callable, there isn't any point in using Runnable is it?

Comment: Neither should be "preferred" over the other... use whichever one makes sense given the context (or given the library method's argument type).

Comment: Not good advice.  Callable is absolutely the one to go with if you're not confined by backwards compatibility.  In other words absolutely prefer Callable over the legacy Runnable.

Comment: @RichieHH - Why?  If you don't need the features of Callable, why use it?

Comment: @sheidaei - given that Runnable is the (slightly) simpler interface, my first reaction would be to use Runnable unless you need some benefit provided by Callable. So I would turn your question around: is there any point in using Callable, when you don't need it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Both have their uses, and both are supported by the Executor framework in java.util.concurrent. Runnable has been around longer, but it is still in use and not discouraged.

Callables can throw exceptions and return values, which makes them the better abstraction for result-bearing tasks (such as fetching a resource from the network, performing an expensive computation of a value, and the like) [from *Java Concurrency in Practice* by Goetz, Bloch et. al., the standard work on Java concurrency].

So, if you are designing an API, I would suggest using Callables when possible. If you are sure that the tasks will not return values and will not throw exceptions, then Runnables are also a valid choice. There is no black and white here, especially because Runnables can easily be wrapped in Callables and vice versa.

As an aside, note that your Callable implementation need not declare `throws Exception`; the fact that Callable itself declares it is only to allow implementors to throw any checked exceptions. Callers of your Callable who rely solely on the Callable interface will have to write exception handling code, though.
Also note that Callables need not return a value; you can simply declare your Callable to return `Void` (with capital '`V`').

Answer (score 8):

IMHO, Runnable is a better type to use when taking as argument a function which

- doesn't have a returned value, but only side effects
- must handle exceptions, and not propagate them

Don't forget that `Callable.call()` throws Exception. That means that if you take a Callable as argument, this Callable can throw any kind of exception, and you must have a way to handle them all in a correct way. If you can't do that, it's better to let the implementor of the Callable handle the exception as he wants to, and make the argument a Runnable to make that clear.

Answer (score 7):

Use case of not using `Callable`: `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate` and `scheduleWithFixedDelay` accepts only `Runnable`.

Comment: Nice, concise use case for Runnable!

Comment: The case for older code enforcing use of runnable was already well covered.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer `Callable`s, but in those rare instances you might need a `Callable` to be `Runnable`, you can easily implement both by adding a `run()` method like this to your `Callable`.

```
public void run(){
    try{
        call();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(); // or however you log errors
    }
}
```

In Java 8, you can also make an interface to do the same thing for you:

```
public interface CallableRunnable<T> extends Callable<T>, Runnable {
    default void run(){
        try {
            call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // or however you log errors
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just have to change anything that `implements Callable<T>` to `implements CallableRunnable<T>`.That way, your jobs can always be called by any method that requires either. Of course, if you need specific error handling, you can still override the run() method to handle the exceptions thrown by your `call()` method. You could even implement a method to do so:

```
public interface CallableRunnable<T> extends Callable<T>, Runnable {
    default void run(){
        try {
            call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            handleCallExceptions(e);
        }
    }

    default void handleCallExceptions(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then any special exception handling only needs to implement its own `handleExceptions(Exception)` method... but you don't have to if you don't need to. I prefer this because it allows you to have an implementation that uses your logging framework, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Callable and **Runnable** both is similar to each other and can use in implementing thread. In case of implementing **Runnable** you must implement **run()** method but in case of callable you must need to implement **call()** method, both method works in similar ways but callable **call()** method have more flexibility.There is some differences between them.

Difference between **Runnable** and **callable** as below--

1) The **run()** method of **runnable** returns **void**, means if you want your thread return something which you can use further then you have **no choice with Runnable run()** method. There is a solution **'Callable'**, If you want to return any thing in form of **object** then you **should use Callable instead of Runnable**. Callable interface have method **'call()' which returns Object**.

Method signature -
Runnable->

```
public void run(){}
```

Callable->

```
public Object call(){}
```

2) In case of **Runnable run()** method if any checked exception arises then you must **need to handled with try catch block**, but in case of **Callable call()** method you **can throw checked exception** as below

```
 public Object call() throws Exception {}
```

3) **Runnable** comes from legacy **java 1.0** version, but **callable** came in **Java 1.5** version with **Executer** framework.

If you are familiar with **Executers** then you should **use Callable instead of Runnable**.

Hope you understand.