# Best way handle result from thread on UI

Tags: android, android-runonuithread

I want to save data to DB in new `Thread` and after that show `toast` on the `UI`.

Method for saving:

```
public void addToBasket(String text) {

        new Thread(() -> {

                //emulate save
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000L);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              //after that I need say ti UI thread - show Toast!
        }).start();
    }
```

I call this method:

```
BasketService.me().addToBasket(result.getContents());
```

I do now want use `AsyncTask` for this. Please tell me the best way to implement such tasks

Comment: `runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){ public void run(){}}):`

Comment: Use runOnUiThread() batter understand : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31549559/7666442

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most concise way to run a simple background task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950047/most-concise-way-to-run-a-simple-background-task)

Answer (score -1):

**batter to use:**

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                //Do what ever you want do man 
            }
        });
```

`runOnUiThread()` method to manipulate your `UserInterface` from background threads.

Comment: you can not use Toast and other UI operation in doInBackgroud() because may be you will be a create network operation on that

Comment: Yup it is not a best way but should be relevent  for you

Answer (score -1):

In case of callback from a nonUi thread to Ui thread you can use runOnUiThread()(As specified above) or Handler. Below is a example of using handler.

```
 protected static final Handler mainThreadHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

protected void onSuccessInMainThread(final R result, final Bundle bundle) {
    mainThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            callback.onSuccess(result, bundle);
        }
    });
}

protected void onErrorInMainThread(final Exception error) {
    mainThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            callback.onError(error);
        }
    });
}
```