# Where to use callable and where to use Runnable Interface?

Tags: java, runnable, callable

I am quite new to Java, I was going through concepts of Multithreading, while going through various implementation of using multithreading, I went through these two concepts.
This [The difference between the Runnable and Callable interfaces in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141284/the-difference-between-the-runnable-and-callable-interfaces-in-java) question specifies what is difference between the two and where to use.

My doubt is if Callable is capable of doing everything that Runnable, why so many people use Runnable instead of callable?
Are there any extra overheads in implementing Callable interface in comparison with Runnable Inteface?

Comment: You shouldn't use Callable, if you don't need it. As [KISS principle](https://people.apache.org/~fhanik/kiss.html) states.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before there was the `java.util.concurrent` package, which landed in the Java 5 release, there was really no other options to doing concurrent computation, but to directly manipulate `Thread`s.

You could manipulate threads directly, e.g. by subclassing:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        myComputation();
    }
}
```

Or you could do the same by creating a `Runnable`, which was the preferred way (mainly because you do not need to subclass anything, which provides a clear separation of concern, better code reuse or generally, a better composition):

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        mycomputation();
    }
}
new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start();
```

But no matter which way you used, you had to create, launch, manipulate, join on threads. Which has drawbacks: how many threads can you create? Is this expensive? (At some point, it is, although it became cheaper and cheaper with each JVM implementation.)

Plus, this API itself has limitations that the developer had to overcome: what if I want to return a value from a `Runnable`, seeing the signature does not allow it anyway? How can I know if my `Runnable` failed with an `Exception`? There things such as exception handlers and the like to allow for that with threads, but it was quiet a repetitive, error prone, task.

Enters the `java.util.concurrent` package! It offers an answer to all this (and more)!

You want to reuse threads for more than one "unit of work" (be it a `Runnable`or not?): you can. Want to know if the "unit of work" completed or failed: you can. Want to return a value: you can. Want to dynamically prioritize some tasks above others? Sure. Need the ability to schedule tasks? Can do. And so on.

Replace your `Runnable`s with `Callable`s (this is simple as can be, both are single method interfaces!), stop manipulating `Thread`s in favor of `Future`s and leave the plumbing to `ExecutorService`.

> My doubt is if Callable is capable of doing everything that Runnable, why so many people use Runnable instead of callable?

Maybe they do have old code (Java 1.4?). Maybe they are not aware of the benefits of the higher level abstractions, and prefer the low level `Thread` stuff?

Generally speaking, there is absolutely no reason to prefer using `Thread`s since the concurrent API came.

> Are there any extra overheads in implementing Callable interface in comparison with Runnable Interface?

In "implementing `Callable`" vs `Runnable`, no there is none. But there is a cost to the new `Callable` stuff because internally, it all comes back down to `Thread`s and `Runnable`s (at least, the current implementations do this). But you might actually gain performance, because of new capabilities like easier thread reuse!

So, yes, the concurrent API has its cost, but it is absolutely, completely negligible in any standard use case, but it also has new strengths that make it better in many ways, including performance.

Plus, you get massive new possibilities from the API, as already stated (see the Fork/Join framework, see the parallel streams in Java 8, ...), and reduce the need for any kink of "custom", "self made" concurrency code for said functionalities, which is notoriously hard to get right.

The benefit/cost ratio completely favors the "new" concurrent API.

Answer (score 4):

> My doubt is if Callable is capable of doing everything that Runnable, why so many people use Runnable instead of callable? Are there any extra overheads in implementing Callable interface in comparison with Runnable Inteface?

1. Use `Runnable` interface for ***fire and forget*** calls, especially when you  are not interested in result of the task execution.
2. There are no extra overheads in implementation of `Callable` interface.

The key difference from documentation [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)

> The `Callable` interface is similar to `Runnable`, in that both are designed for classes whose instances are potentially executed by another thread. A `Runnable`, however, does not return a result and cannot throw a checked exception.

Lets check the source code of [AbstractExecutorService](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.java/?v=source)

```
public Future<?> submit(Runnable task) {
    if (task == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    RunnableFuture<Object> ftask = newTaskFor(task, null);
    execute(ftask);
    return ftask;
}


public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task) {
    if (task == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    RunnableFuture<T> ftask = newTaskFor(task);
    execute(ftask);
    return ftask;
}
```

I don't see any overhead in execution of `Callable` task as `Callable` internally uses `RunnableFuture<T>`

Answer (score 2):

One important difference: the `run()` method in the `Runnable` interface returns void; the `call()` method in the `Callable` interface returns an object of type `T`.  This allows you to access a response object easily.

You can do the same thing with a concrete implementation of `Runnable` by creating a private data member and providing a getter, but the syntactic sugar is sweet.

Answer (score 0):

> why so many people use Runnable instead of callable?

Callable is competitively new in jdk, which came with Executor framework, provide more flexibility on thread execution.

> Are there any extra overheads in implementing Callable interface in
>   comparison with Runnable Inteface?

I dont think so, it is very straight forward if you follow any standard Executor documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> My doubt is if Callable is capable of doing everything that Runnable, why so many people use Runnable instead of callable?

That question is tantamount to asking, "Why does Java have static types?"  An interface is a declaration of a compile-time type signature, nothing more, nothing less; and the only difference between any two interfaces is the compile-time types of the arguments and the return values.

So why does Java have static types?  Unfortunately, that question is way out of scope for StackOverflow.  You can use Google to find all about staticly typed languages vs. dynamically typed languages.

Also, if you want a glimpse of a different world, you can try writing some Ruby code.  There are no interfaces in Ruby because there are no static types.  Ruby programmers talk about "Duck Typing", which is another good phrase to Google.