# Why Executor interface doesn't have a method, which takes Callable as a parameter?

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, callable

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/141303/8913704) I learned that the only difference between `Callable` and `Runnable` is that former can return a result of the execution and throw an exception.

I don't understand why [`Executor`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/Executor.java) doesn't define a method which takes a `Callable`:

```
void execute(Callable command);
```

From my point of view, it'd be logical to create methods for both `Runnable` and `Callable`. In [`ExecutorService`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.java), which is a subinterface of `Executor`, there are similar `submit()` methods for both `Runnable` and `Callable`.

Please, explain this design decision, because I can't find any explanation on the Internet.

Comment: if you really want to know that, you shouldn't be asking this on an open forum, but at those who actually designed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why `Executor` doesn't define a method which takes a `Callable`.

An `Executor` has a single responsibility - *executing a submitted task*. On this abstraction level, APIs that use only `Runnable`s don't demand the additional features proposed by the `ExecutorService`.

> It'd be logical to create methods for both `Runnable` and `Callable`.

Yes, therefore the `ExecutorService` interface was designed by extending the `Executor`. The `ExecutorService` offers a significant difference - *providing results of task execution.* That's why the `Callable`, `TimeUnit`, and lifecycle methods were added.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the Executor design was meant to be as simple as possible, i.e. with one method. Since execute() doesn't provide any means of getting the result, it makes sense that it doesn't accept Callables, and takes only Runnables.

On the other hand, the various submit() functions return Futures, which can be used to both obtain a result (e.g. from a Callable), or to simply wait for the execution to finish. So, it makes sense to accept both Runnable and Callable.

Answer (score 2):

Executors run tasks. They are needed if you want to manage how and when tasks should be run. Executors don't collect task results and thus support only `Runnable`.

Assume they support `Callable`. Then how should one fetch the result? `T execute(Callable<T> command)` is not an option as it will block current thread execution. So it should be paired with some `T getResult()` or return `Future<T>`. And for that you have `ExecutorService` with method `<T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task)`.